# My 2004 Mazda 3 passenger window receives a signal to go down but not up. Could I get a little help?

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, mazda, mazda-3, power-windows

So my 2004 Mazda 3 has an issue with the passenger side window not rolling up. I’ve narrowed it down to an electrical issue on the passenger side motor plug with a current tester. Every other component in conjunction with the window works just fine but the plug to the window motor isn’t receiving a signal to roll up from the door switch or the driver side switch. Not great with electrical stuff and I don't want to be tearin my wire harness apart for no reason, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest you try the motor directly with 12v power to see if it rolls up to eliminate it before you go trudging into the wiring as well. You could also see if there is power from the plug at the motor coming from the switch.

Comment: You'd need a wire diagram to confirm, but many times the circuit from the drivers switch travels through the passenger door switch. This means that the drivers switch could be the only thing wrong. If you know how to use a multimeter, check driver's side switch.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was able to roll up the window by hooking up the motor with an independent power source. As for the plug, it is receiving power and activating properly goin down but sadly its lookin like I'm gonna have to tackle the harness in the morning. 

As for the wire diagram I just just looking at it and hoping to get hands on when it gets cooler and get my hands on a multimeter before I start rooting around to much.